# Calling cloudconvert API inside my REST API

Tags: php, api, curl, slim, cloudconvert

I have created a test function in my REST API (using the SLIM framework) for testing my implementation of a wrapper class for the cloudconvert [API](https://cloudconvert.com/apiconsole).

```
$app->get('/test', 'authenticate', function() use ($app) {

    $response = array();
    $converter = new CloudConverter();
    $url = $converter->createProcess("docx","pdf");
    $response["url"] = $url;  
    echoRespnse(201, $response);            

});
```

**My createProcess function inside CloudConverter class looks like this:**

```
public function createProcess($input_format,$output_format)
{
    $this->log->LogInfo("CreateProcess Called");

    $headers = array('Content-type: application/json');
    $curl_post_data = array('apikey' => API_KEY,'inputformat' => $input_format,'outputformat' => $output_format);        
    $curl = curl_init(CLOUD_CONVERT_HTTP);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curl_post_data));
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($curl_response === false) 
    {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
        $this->log->LogInfo('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
    }

    curl_close($curl);
    $decoded = json_decode($curl_response,true);
    return $decoded['url']; 
}
```

I have tested my API using Chrome Advanced Rest Client and i see a successful response from my call to the cloudconvert API but that is not what i was expecting as can be seen in the code above. I was expecting to extract the url and return THAT in my response.

**My Questions is:**
HOW can i extract the url from the response from cloudconvert and return that in my own response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)
```

to return response as a string: [curl docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was just reading through the curl_setopt options but you beat me to it :) .. again thanks ..